# Import Microsoft.Sharepoint namespace

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, namespaces, caml

Can anyone know, how can I import the Microsoft.Sharepoint dll to a console application? I want to test a CAML query result without deploying a sharepoint site. I added the dll to the app's references and of course the using directive too, but when I build the program it can't find that...

Comment: Maybe you're missing dependencies of the dll. Are you building on a SharePoint server?

Comment: Show us what is exactly the error and when does it occurs (compile time? Startup? runtime?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late reply and thanks the assist for everyone. I founded the problem's solution. The problem occurs at compile time the namespace seemingly missed. The solution was I needed to change the target framework and the target platform to the same as the original Sharepoint application.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio 2010 and assuming you are using Visual Studio in an environment that has Sharepoint. You will find a Sharepoint tab in the Add References section.
Please note that if you use Microsoft.Sharepoint namespace on a console application. You must run the console application on the server where Sharepoint is installed.
 You may consider using the Sharepoint Client Object model. This allows you to connect to Sharepoint from an external location. However, the CAML query is a bit different.